# How can I calculate the average path length of the graph efficiently in graph-tool?

Tags: python-3.x, graph, graph-tool

I am dealing with networks of the order of 10000 vertices and I am using [graph-tool](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/) to analyze them. One of the things that I want to calculate for each of these graphs is the average path length which is defined as the average of the shortest distances over all the pairs of nodes in the graph. So I tried this:

```
ave_path_length = 0
tot = 0

for v1 in G.vertices():
    print(v1)
    for v2 in G.vertices():
        if v1 != v2 :
            tot += 1
            ave_path_length += gt.shortest_distance(G, v1, v2)

ave_path_length /= tot
```

However, this is taking eternity. Is there a better method to achieve the task? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a much efficient way to achieve this. One can do this:

```
import graph_tool.all as gt
dist = gt.shortest_distance(G)
ave_path_length = sum([sum(i) for i in dist])/(G.num_vertices()**2-G.num_vertices())
```

This takes only few seconds for sparse networks of size 10000. However, I am still curious as whether a better method exists.

Answer (score 1):

Can you do,

```
all_sp = gt.shortest_distance(G)
vertex_avgs = graph_tool.stats.vertex_average(G, all_sp)
avg_path = numpy.mean(vertex_avgs[0])
```

I haven't tried this, but this should work.

Answer (score 0):

you can cut the time by 2 by using the fact that `distance(v1,v2) == distance(v2,v1)`. So compute only the half of the values (and divide by half too, but that's handled automatically)

```
vert = G.vertices()  # not sure it is a list. If not just convert to a list first
for i,v1 in enumerate(vert):
    for j in range(i+1,len(vert)):
        tot += 1
        ave_path_length += gt.shortest_distance(G, v1, vert[j])

ave_path_length /= tot
```

apart from that, you could avoid computing `tot`:

```
tot = (len(vert)-1)*(len(vert)-2)//2
```

Comment: That's right. I have implemented that but just didn't show it to avoid complication. That makes the time half of the original but doesn't reduce it substantially.

Comment: see my last edit. I'm afraid there's nothing more you can do, except optimizing `shortest_distance`: i.e: do not use the library (unless it is already native!), do it yourself "inline": avoids parameter passing and function call. Can you try to edit your post showing the inside of this function?